# How do I get data of clicked button row of Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I'm building a site but there is a problem.
I don't know how I can access that data of grid in which row the button is clicked.

.aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlEntry"
    CssClass="style1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReordID" HeaderText="ReordID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ReordID"
            Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailID" HeaderText="EmailID" SortExpression="EmailID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="Grid_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlEntry" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Entry]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

.CS file:

```
protected void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
    resetdata();
}
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "INSERT INTO Entry (Name, EmailID, Password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "');";
    Connection conn = new Connection(str);
    Refresh_Click(sender, e);
}
protected void resetdata()
{
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    TextBox3.Text = "";
}
protected void Grid_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "DELETE FROM Entry WHERE RecordID = @RecordID";
    Connection conn = new Connection(str);
    GridView1.DataBind();
    resetdata();
}
```

Connection Class:

```
public Connection(string qry)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

How can I delete the data from SQL Server 2005 using this webpage?
What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a `CommandArgument` and a `CommandName` to your button that contains the ID -

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval('ReordID') %>" CommandName="REMOVE" OnClick="Grid_Click" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

... then add a `RowCommand` event to the GridView -

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.CommandName=="REMOVE")
    {
        int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //Do Sql Here
    }
}
```

Comment: There are error occur : Parser Error

Line 50:             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="Delete">
Line 51:                 <ItemTemplate>
Line 52:                     <asp:Button ID="Button3" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ReordID") %>"
Line 53:                         CommandName="REMOVE" />
Line 54:                 </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
.net frame work 3.5
Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: It's working with : 
`<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReordID") %>' CommandName="dele"
                        Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>`

and

`if (e.CommandName == "dele")
        {
            string str = "DELETE FROM Entry WHERE ReordID = '" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "'";
            Connection conn = new Connection(str);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            resetdata();
        }`

@Evan Thank for help...

Comment: Ah I see the typo I made - fixed it for anyone else stumbling along on this. Great news it works!